# xcode 4.2: where is "Distribute for Enterprise" button?

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning-profile

Does anyone know, where is that button? I'm using latest xcode 4.2.
Here is my sharing dialog:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the ipa option when you click on next it will ask you for the ipa file name. You'll find a check box there "Save for enterprise distribution" just select it and you are good to go. See below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want the ".ipa" option (which you have already selected, so that's good).  Then you want to pick your Enterprise Distribution .mobileprovision from the Identity popup.  (You also need to make sure you used that .mobileprovision in the project's Code Signing build settings.)

Once you've saved the .ipa you need to distribute it and the .mobileprovision to your enterprise users.  You could email it, or put it in a shared folder and then they can take those files and drop them into iTunes, then sync their devices.  Much nicer is distributing over the air using an HTTP server.  Instructions here: http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

Comment: thanks for the answer. one thing is worrying me... what is Enterprise Distribution? is it some special kind of distribution except AdHoc and AppStore distribution? I see only those two options on distribution profile creation page (in developer account).

Comment: Enterprise is special, you need a special type of developer account for it.  Since your question was "where is distribute for enterprise" I assumed that was what you were looking for.  It's much the same procedure for "standard" adhoc, except I would recommend investigating testflightapp.com.  They make things a LOT simpler in many ways.